# Unable to create a smart folder based on Samsung camera model

Tags: photos, mojave

Here is the info of a typical photo, captured by a Samsung andriod phone, in my Photo library:

[image]

I tried the following condition in a new smart folder to show Samsung photo exclusively.

[image]

But it yields zero photo!

I have created similar smart folder before and they work. Here is an example:

[image]

Why smart folder fails for 'Samsung'? How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you double checked to see if your query is case sensitive? Also you should check out RegEx, it’s a way to search for files using finder with raw queries. An app that will allow you to view all Exif tags on your images will give you all available meta tags that you can search for.

Comment: Tested - query is not case-sensitive. Also, once it's had a few seconds to think [I initially tested using 'includes nikon'] it then shows in the drop-menu the entire list of models it can recognise in the Library, which builds up over a minute or two, presumably as it scans. https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWgEZ.png All I could suggest is try 'includes' rather than 'starts with'.

Answer (score 1):

There are EXIF tags for both Camera `Manufacturer` and camera `Model`.

The example on wikipedia shows:

```
| Tag          | Value       |
|:-------------|------------:|
| Manufacturer |       CASIO |
| Model        |     QV-4000 |
```

It appears that the Photos `Get Info` panel is concatenating these two tags. But only the Camera Model is available for Smart Album filtering.

If you change your smart album to search for your camera *model*, `SM-G950F`, it should find the photos.

There does not appear to be a way to filter via the camera *manufacturer*, `samsung`.

I can confirm your findings with my `FUJIFILM X100T`.